# null pointer exception in android

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
public void but(View v){
  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "nai", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Messaging.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want to open another activity from my main activity. Another class is Messaging. It has another layout named `messaging_layout`. In the code there are no error but after run this code, when I press this button program crashes and throws a NullPointerException.

If I omit

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Messaging.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

the button will work properly.

Comment: please properly format and indent code

Comment: As there is no chance of an NPE in your two lines of code, I assume the problem is in the class `Messaging`. Please learn to read stack traces, post the stack trace and the referenced code sections. And BTW, just because your IDE does not show any errors in your code, you should not assume that you did not make any mistakes.

Comment: The constructor for Intent looks plain wrong.  Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: @Antman06 can you explain how its wrong? because i dont see that it's wrong!

Comment: Nvm he's using MainActivity.this to get the context.  Id guess that one of those params is null but MainActivity can be ruled out as being null since his MainActivity is already loaded.  Perhaps a problem then with Messaging.class as still_learning mentions.  Probably an manifest.xml issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some error in Message class or forgot to add activity tag into manifest file or your clicking event,

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO your operation.
        }
    });
```

into your onCreate() function.